# are three columns the same (not including NA)

Tags: r

so I have three columns with codes, sort of like this:

```
code1= c("AAA", NA, "221", "444", "BBB")
code2= c(NA, "CCC", NA, NA, "BBB")
code3= c(NA, NA, "222", "444", "BBB")
df <-data.frame(code1, code2, code3)
```

I want to know if all the rows have the same value, not including the NA's. So, in the case above, everything except row 3 should be TRUE, or, alternatively, 1's and 0's.

I have tried this:

```
df$codecheck<- ifelse((df$code1 == df$code2) & 
                          (df$code1== df$code3), 1,0)
```

Which isn't getting me anywhere. Any advice?

Comment: `df$codecheck<-ifelse(is.na(df[,1] == df[,2] & df[,1] == df[,3] & df[,2] == df[,3]), 1, ifelse(df[,1]==df[,2] & df[,1]==df[,3], 1, 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` and an extra function:

```r
isFalse <- function(x){sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) isFALSE(x[i]))}

df %>% 
  mutate(codecheck = if_any(starts_with("code"), ~isFalse(. == coalesce(code1, code2, code3))))
  code1 code2 code3 codecheck
1   AAA  <NA>  <NA>     FALSE
2  <NA>   CCC  <NA>     FALSE
3   221  <NA>   222      TRUE
4   444  <NA>   444     FALSE
5   BBB   BBB   BBB     FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the length of the vector of unique non-na elements is 1 for each row.

```
df$codecheck <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1)

df
#   code1 code2 code3 codecheck
# 1   AAA  <NA>  <NA>      TRUE
# 2  <NA>   CCC  <NA>      TRUE
# 3   221  <NA>   222     FALSE
# 4   444  <NA>   444      TRUE
# 5   BBB   BBB   BBB      TRUE
```